# Fortune 1000 companies: which are public utilities?

Tags: equities, edgar, classifier

I am reviewing the Fortune 1000 list of companies. Is there a reliable way using information from EDGAR filings to determine which of these companies are primarily acting as regulated public utilities?

Comment: Are you looking for an automated or manual way?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a list you can download from NASDAQ.

[Nasdaq Industry List](http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-industry.aspx?industry=Public%20Utilities)

Comment: Although this is not from EDGAR as requested so this list is not exhaustive.

Answer (score 2):

Just from the EDGAR SIC codes, it won't be possible to tell which are regulated to my knoweldge - this classification method specifically applies to companies by industry. The 4900-4999 is going to be your area of interest though:

[image]